# HTML 5 validation not working in Firefox with Knockout options binding

Tags: html, validation, firefox, knockout.js

I am trying to force users to choose an option in a drop down menu, populated by Knockout. I am using the HTML5 "required" validation attribute, and it works fine in Chrome 38, and Opera 25, but it fails in Firefox 33.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" class="form-horizontal form-validate" action="" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">To</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select required data-bind="options: listRecipients,
                                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...', 
                                   optionsText: 'name',
                                   value: selectedRecipient"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

And the corresponding JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function AppViewModel() {
        // KO model
        self.listRecipients = ko.observableArray([{
            name: 'foo',
            id: '1'
        }, {
            name: 'bar',
            id: '2'
        }]);
        self.selectedRecipient = ko.observable();
    }

    // Activates knockout.js
    var appViewModel = new AppViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);
});
```

Corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/0onuefdg/).

Using jQuery validation with Knockout "options" seems rather complex, and I cannot find much documentation on using knockout-validation with "options" either... any idea why it is not working  in FF?

Answer (score 0):

Knockout sports databind optionsValue so if it was id you wanted to store in observable selectedRecipient, just add optionsValue:'id'

```
<form id="theForm" class="form-horizontal form-validate" action="" method="post">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">To</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select required data-bind="options: listRecipients,
                                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...', 
                                   optionsValue: 'id',   
                                   optionsText: 'name',
                                   value: selectedRecipient"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

Corresponding [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/0onuefdg/1/)